# The project file specified already exists? Can't import to Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I keep trying to import a project that my teacher sent us as an example into Android Studio but I can't get it to work. It keeps saying that "The project file specified already exists" and I don't know what to do. I have tried uninstalling Android Studio completely and reinstalling it and it still says that the project file exists which makes no sense as I literally cannot have any projects on there with a fresh install. I made sure to delete all other files related to it too. All my workspaces are clear. Does anyone have an idea of what's going on?

Comment: Have you checked that the directory on your system in which your Android projects are stored is empty?

Comment: I have and it is empty. It makes no sense. I think I'm misunderstanding something about AndroidStudio .

Comment: Checked that no .idea file there? It is a hidden file.

Comment: but even if there is one, it's not for the project I am trying to upload. How do I find it on android studio

Answer (score 1):

If you're tryna import it as is(Project.zip) you're gonna wanna unzip first so android studio wouldn't rip. 2Pac was playin' that's why

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I just renamed the folder name and imported as normal in Android Studio.
Remember to rebuild project, so directory is correct to your system